# Regular Expression for both float and integer with range

Tags: regex

I am working on a regular expression, can someone help me out. Expression Required for `0` to `150.00`

Valid Cases: `22.44`, `22.00`, `22`, `22.0`, `0`, `150`, `150.0`, `150.00` etc
Invalid Cases: `150.01`, `150.1`

I have my Regex but it is not supporting `150` as an input

My Regex is:

```
/^(?!<0)([<>]?)([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-4][0-9]|150\.[0][0])(\.[0-9]?[0-9])?$/
```

Comment: Regular expression are not an ideal tool to solve this problem - if possible, it would be much better to use parseFloat() and check the range with an if statement.

Comment: Why do you need a regex for this? It seems like the last thing you should be using

Comment: @DuncanThacker, why regex is not ideal. can you give some insight about that. I got the regex and its working fine, so do you still think i need to avoid this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here you go this regex will work on your validations-

```
^(([0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|[1][0-4][0-9])?(\.[0-9]{0,2})?|(150)|(150\.00))$
```